# Sonar python files without .py suffix

Tags: python, sonarqube, filenames, executable

When I specify a Python executable script file that does not end in .py suffx, Sonar runs successfully but the report has no content. I have tried specifying `-Dsonar.python.file.suffixes=""` but that makes no difference.

`sonar-runner -Dsonar.sources=/users/av/bin -Dsonar.inclusions=gsave -Dsonar.issuesReport.html.location=/ws/av-rcd/SA_Reports/PY-SA_report-2014-7-2-15-13-44.html -Dsonar.language=py -Dsonar.python.file.suffixes=""`

How can I make sonar analyze a python executable script that does nothave a .py suffix?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to do so. 
Empty string as value of property "sonar.python.file.suffixes" is ignored.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It sure would be more useful to have sonar not enforce the suffix requirement when the user explicitly supplies the file names with a sonar.inclusions specification.

Comment: @a-v: in case of a mono-language project, indeed I can understand that a user would expect SonarQube to be clever enough to understand that a file set on "sonar.inclusions" is supposed to be of the specified language. Our ultimate goal is to include all files and make only multi-language analyses, and in this case it is quite challenging to perfectly guess the language of a file w/o an extension.

Comment: Agreed that if SonarQube has to auto-figure out the language, it can be a challenge. But, in this case, this is not needed. Please notice the specification of the -Dsonar.language=py in the command. This should serve to tell Sonarqube that all files in the sonar.inclusions are of the specified language type.